# Numberformat max integer digits not working as needed

Tags: java, number-formatting

I need to format a number, ideally using numberformat. Currently i have:

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMaximumIntegerDigits(4);
    System.out.println(nf.format(123456.1234));
```

This results in 3.456,12
However, i *want* to have 1.234,12 as a result. Is there an easy way to accomplish that with numberformat?

Comment: Wait.  You want 1.234,12, completely skipping over the 56 in between?!

Comment: Correct. I can do it with substrings etc but numberformat handles it pretty conveniently otherwise including handling multiple . or ,

Comment: I don't think `NumberFormat` will handle that -- that's a _very_ nonstandard demand, just to _skip_ intermediate digits instead of rounding them.

Comment: It can be rounded if possible, it doesnt really matter in this particular situation.

Comment: I thought you wanted to skip the digits 56, not round them.

Comment: Maybe explain why you're doing it a bit more, and all will become clear

Comment: He is asking for the formatting to occur before rounding...so he doesn't care whether it gets rounded or not. He wants to get 'rid' of it (the 56). Is that wrong Martijin?

Comment: That's right. The reason i want this in this way is we have a legacy application still running that uses numberformat in it's form validation to make sure there are not more than 2 digits left when parsing user input. Now someone said "yeah we want the same thing for the part before the dots, just get rid of extra numbers". Since it's a legacy application, noone wants any big changes. If it can be done by just modifying the numberformat that would be ideal.

Comment: Are you sure you understand the requirements? Under what scenario would it make sense to take a value 123456,78 and display it as 1234,78 (using European decimal format)?  Is this value semantically a number or something else?

Comment: I understand the specs correctly :) Its a number used later on for conversion to bigdecimal (currency). As i said its a legacy app that will be phased out and the question was if this could be done with a *VERY* minor adjustment.  If it cant be done with the numberformat method i'll just leave it be.

There are a lot of things that can be done better in this app, this is one of them, but it's marked for replacement for a reason so...

Answer (score 1):

setMaximumFractionDigits() and setMaximumIntegerDigits() define the maximum amount of digits that will appear on the formatted number (for the fraction part and the integer part respectively).

They do not set upper bounds to the digits that will be part of the formatted string.

You can check the api here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits(int)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumIntegerDigits(int)

If you want to filter out digits you have to do it yourself (afaik). Here's a quick example:

```
    String[] parts = "123456.1234".split("\\.");

    String integerPart = parts[0].replaceAll("[^0-4]", "");
    String decimalPart = parts[1].replaceAll("[^0-2]", "");

    float filteredFloat = Float.parseFloat(integerPart + "." + decimalPart);

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    System.out.println(nf.format(filteredFloat));
```

This should return the localized String version of 1234.12